# gcc shared library failed linking to glibc

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I'm writing a simple C shared library using Eclipse CDT under Linux 64bit.

The code has one reference to the `rand()` function in the `<stdlib.h>` It compiles fine but when linking it reports the following error from the linker:

```
gcc -shared -o "libalg.so"  ./sort.o   
/usr/bin/ld: ./sort.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `rand@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
```

sort.o is the object file compiled from the file. libalg.so is the target shared library name.

Can anyone explaining why this happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried recompiling passing `-fPIC` to gcc as the error message suggests?

Comment: Not yet, I'm just trying to understand the problem first.

Comment: and apparently add -fPIC solve the problem.

Comment: It's a gory linkage issue and I'm not good enough with that to be really helpful, but basically, programs are loaded at a predictable address but shared libraries are not. The predictable address of programs enables the linker to use tricks for finding symbols that can't be used with libraries. Compiling to position-independent code (PIC means position-independent code) allows other tricks that work with libraries, but it comes with different tradeoffs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On `x86_64` architecture `gcc` requires you to use `-fPIC` i.e Position Independent Code by default.

The underlying reason for the error is that the relocation type for the symbol `rand` is of type `R_X86_64_PC32` which means that it is PC relative and should lie within `32bit` offset from the following instruction.

But the current architecture is of `x86_64` type which means that it can lie anywhere within the `64bit` address space.

So the dynamic linker actually can not link a symbol with such a relocation type.

Either you have to use `-fPIC` or compile your code using the `-mcmodel=large` which will actually make the relocation type to `R_X86_64_64`.

For more details on how linking is done refer to this great blog by [Eli Bendersky](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/11/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries-on-x64/)