# Error while compiling a shared library

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

Using gcc I am trying to make a shared library on a x86_64 system. The code is

```
int myglob = 42;

int ml_func(int a, int b)
{
    myglob += a;
    return b + myglob;
}
```

Compiling it with `gcc -c -g code.c -o code.o` and then `gcc -shared code.o -o libcode.so` throws and error!

The error is `/usr/bin/ld: libconst.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol 'myglob' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`.

So I tried compiling it with **-fPIC** flag but it throws the same error.

**Note:** I am trying to see load time relocation in libraries so I connot use the flag `-fPIC`.

Comment: is `myglob` used outside of the library ? Did you try to make it `static` ?

Comment: you see if I compile with `gcc code.c -o libcode.so -shared` it gets compiled successfully but if I try to make a object file and then make the shared library it thows an error!

Comment: The background for this question is learning [Load-time relocation](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/25/load-time-relocation-of-shared-libraries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On x86_64 architecture gcc requires you to use `-fPIC` (Position Independent Code). This is because relocation type for the symbols rand is of type R_X86_64_PC32. What you could do is use `-mcmodel=large` which will set the relocation type to R_X86_64_64.

```
gcc -g -mcmodel=large -c code.c -o code.o
gcc -shared -o libcode.so code.o
```

Better explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21224447/6573268).

Comment: No I can't use -fPIC because I have to analyze load time relocaton.

Comment: I missed that part. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If `myglob` is not used outside of the code in the library you could specify the `static` storage class for the variable. A `static` global variable will be located in the `BSS` segment.

Example:

```
static int myglob = 42;

int ml_func(int a, int b)
{
    myglob += a;
    return b + myglob;
}
```