# collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status on making .so file with codeblocks (64 bit version)

Tags: c++, codeblocks, ubuntu-18.04

my problem is in making .so file in codeblocks , the project that make my .so file in older version(32 bit) is failed with following errors in new version(64 bit)

```
/usr/bin/ld: obj/Debug/src/tester.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_ZTV6tester' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

the codeblocks command line

```
g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g -Iinclude -c /home/amini/codes/testr/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g -Iinclude -c /home/amini/codes/testr/src/tester.cpp -o obj/Debug/src/tester.o
g++ -shared  obj/Debug/main.o obj/Debug/src/tester.o  -o bin/Debug/liblibTestso.so -m64 -fPIC
```

help me to solve this , many thanks

Comment: If you go to your favorite search engine and search for e.g. `relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol` you will find quite a lot of results. Many from here on Stack Overflow. Please do that first, and read through at least a few of the hits.

Comment: Or just follow what the error says. recompile with `-fPIC`.

Comment: @samini You didn't recompile, you've just relinked... Clean the project and compile at least the module which contains the symbol with -fPIC to get a relocatable object. And then link.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I did !. one interesting note when I use the destructor  instead of virtual destructor in tester class the errors disapear

Comment: @samini Without code we cannot help much

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I saw these links , this one is very similar ro my case but didn't solve my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224090/gcc-shared-library-failed-linking-to-glibc/21224447#21224447

Comment: Did you remove the object file `tester.o` and rebuild it with the `-fPIC` option?

Comment: You need to compile with -fPIC, not just link with -fPIC.

Comment: use `-fPIC` on everything or nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw many links about this error, no one clearly answered my question
when you migrate from 32bit to 64 bit Linux system codeblocks gives the mentioned error

by adding the -fPIC to compiler option the problem does not solve because other object files don't make with that option then you should go to setting> compiler> other setting> advance option and add -fPIC there